# After converting c# to vb.net there is an error

Tags: vb.net

maybe there is the best solution to the error problem I am facing

thanks

```
'error End of statement expected
Public Property Name() As String Implements ISearchable.Name = String.Empty

'Character constant must contain exactly one character and Expression expected
txtTotal.Text = $"TOTAL" & vbLf & "{Order.GetTotal(record.SessionId).ToString("C2")}"
```

Comment: The first line should be `Public Property Name As String = String.Empty Implements ISearchable.Name`. In the second line, you need a `$` right before `"{Order...."` (or you could just use `$"TOTAL{vbLf}{Order.GetTotal(record.SessionId).ToString("C2")}"`.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine , `Public Property Name As String = String.Empty Implements ISearchable.Name` and `$"TOTAL{vbLf}{Order.GetTotal(record.SessionId).ToString("C2")}"` your answer is really perfect and can answer as an answer so that I can mark your answer

Comment: It's surprising to use interpolation where the only thing going into the string is the interpolated value.  Why not just concatenate in `Order.GetTotal(record.SessionId).ToString("C2")` instead?

Comment: @Craig , Your answer is also correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the answer from @41686d6564standsw.Palestine so perfect

```
Public Property Name As String = String.Empty Implements ISearchable.Name
txtTotal.Text = $"TOTAL{vbLf}{Order.GetTotal(record.SessionId).ToString("C2")}"
```

and also As per the answer from @Craig so perfect

```
txtTotal.Text = $"TOTAL{Order.GetTotal(record.SessionId).ToString("C2")}"
```

Comment: For the record, my suggestion was `txtTotal.Text = "TOTAL" & vblf & Order.GetTotal(record.SessionId).ToString("C2")`.